# What is the internal structure of an object of the (EDIT: MFC)  CString class?

Tags: c++, mfc, format, cstring

I need to `strncpy()` (effectively) from a (**Edit: MFC) CString object  to a C string variable. It's well known that `strncpy()` sometimes fails (depending on the source length **EDIT** and the length specified in the call) to terminate the dest C string correctly. To avoid that evil, I'm thinking to store a NUL char inside the CString source object and then to `strcpy()` or `memmove()` that guy.

Is this a reasonable way to go about it? If so, what must I manipulate inside the CString object? If not, then what's an alternative that will guarantee a properly-terminated destination C string?

Comment: `CString` doesn't exist in the C++ standard library. Are you talking about `std::string` or something else (maybe the `CString` from [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea(v=vs.100).aspx))?

Comment: Can't you just convert it to `std::string`? E.g.: `std::string cppString(yourCString);`. If you really want the raw string, get it from `cppString.c_str()`. Just beware some Unicode conversions won't work.

Comment: You should definitely use std::string in preference to CString in almost all cases.

Comment: Do you mean that CString should be std::string and C string variable a character array

Comment: @111111: Well, except in the case where one is working in MFC and therefore has to use `CString` to interface with MFC code. You know, the case he's in *right now*, since that's why he has a `CString` to begin with. Look, I love the standard C++ library too, but *way* too many C++ programmers forget that some people work with software that has its own string types, and you can't always use `std::string`. Your advise is useless to his needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strncpy()` only "fails" to null-terminate the destination string when the source string is longer than the length limit you specify.  You can ensure that the destination is null-terminated by setting its last character to null yourself.  For example:

```
#define DEST_STR_LEN 10

char dest_str[DEST_STR_LEN + 1];  // +1 for the null
strncpy(dest_str, src_str, DEST_STR_LEN);
dest_str[DEST_STR_LEN] = '\0';
```

If `src_str` is more than `DEST_STR_LEN` characters long, `dest_str` will be a properly-terminated string of `DEST_STR_LEN` characters.  If `src_str` is shorter than that, `strncpy()` will put a null terminator somewhere within `dest_str`, so the null at the very end is irrelevant and harmless.

Comment: but the question was on CString! I fail to see how this answer, it's just a little relevant.

Comment: @chac, I answered the actual *problem* (incorrect use of `strncpy()`) rather than the *question* (how to implement a misguided workaround for the problem).

Answer (score 1):

[CSimpleStringT::GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k59cayc6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) gives a pointer to a null-terminated string. Use this as the soure for `strncpy`. As this is C++, you should only use C-style strings when interfacing with legacy APIs. Use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I hope they don't changed from when I used them: that was many years ago :)

They used an interesting 'trick' to handle the refcount and the very fast and efficient automatic conversion to char*: i.e the pointer is to LPCSTR, but some back byte is reserved to keep the implementation state.

So the struct can be *used* with the older windows API (LPCSTR without overhead). I found at the time the idea interesting!

Of course the key ìs the availability of allocators: they simply offsets the pointer when mallocing/freeing.

I remember there was a *buffer request* to (for instance) modify the data available: GetBuffer(0), followed by ReleaseBuffer().

HTH

Answer (score 1):

One of the alternative ways would be to zero string first and then cast or memcpy from CString.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not compiling with `_UNICODE` enabled, then you can get a `const char *` from a `CString` very easily. Just cast it to an `LPCTSTR`:

```
CString myString("stuff");
const char *byteString = (LPCTSTR)myString;
```

This is guaranteed to be NULL-terminated.

If you *have* built with `_UNICODE`, then `CString` is a UTF-16 encoded string. You can't really do anything directly with that.

If you do need to copy the data from the `CString`, this very easy, even using C-style code. Just make sure that you allocate sufficient memory and are copying the right length:

```
CString myString("stuff");
char *outString = (char*)malloc(myString.Length() + 1);
strncpy(outString, (LPCTSTR)myString, myString.Length());
```

Answer (score 1):

CString ends with NULL so as long as your text is correct (no NULL characters inside) then copying should be safe. You can write:

```
char szStr[256];
strncpy(szStr, (LPCSTR) String, 3);
szStr[3]='\0'; /// b-cos no null-character is implicitly appended to the end of destination
```

if you store null somehere inside CString object you will probably cause yourself more problems, CString stores its lenght internally.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution would rather involve support from CPU or compiler, as it's much better approach - simply make sure that when copying memory in "safe" mode, at any time after every atomic operation there is zero added on the end, so when whole loop fails, the destination string will still be terminated, without need to zero it fully before making copy.
There could be also support for fast zero - just mark start and stop of zeroed region and it's instantly cleared in RAM, this would make things a lot easier.